# Deep learning - Find patterns combining images and bios data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I was wondering if is it possible combining images and some "bios" data for finding patterns. For example, if I want to know if a image is a cat or dog and I have:

Enough image data for train my model

Enough "bios" data like:

```
size of the animal

size of the tail

weight

height
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a simple yes or no answer? In that case, yes. You are in complete control over building your models which includes what data you make them process and what predictions you get.

If you actually wanted to ask on how to do it, it will depend on specific datasets and application but one way to do it would be by having two models, one specialized for determining the output label (cat or dog) from the image - so perhaps some kind of a simple CNN. The other would process the text data and find patterns in that. Then at the end, you could have either a non-AI evaluator that would combine these two predictions into one naively or you could have both of these models as an input to a simple neural network that would learn pattern from the output of these two models.

That is just one way to possibly do it though and, as I said, the exact implementation will depend on a lot of other factors. How are both of the datasets labeled? Are the data connected to each other? Meaning that, for each picture, do you have some textual data that is for that specific image? Or do you jsut have a spearated dataset of pictures and separate dataset of biological information?

There is also the consideration that you'll probably want to make about the necessity of this approach. Current models can predict categories from processing images with super-human precision. Unless this is an excersise in creating a more complex model, this seems like an overkill.

**PS**: I wouldn't use term "bios" in this context, I believe it is not a very common usage and here on SO it will mostly confuse people into thinking you mean the actual [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS).